# PHP making new row after 3 post records

Tags: php, foreach, split

I'm trying to make a new table row or new break after each set of 3 records from the database.

I have include part of the code:

```
<?php foreach ($payment_methods as $payment_method) {?>
    <?php if ($payment_method['code'] == $code || !$code) { ?>

        <?php $code = $payment_method['code']; ?>
        <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>"/>
    <?php } ?>
    <label for="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>"><?php echo $payment_method['title']; ?></label>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I want to make a <tr> or <br> after 3 record...

Comment: All my payment methods, are of 6 choices in total, and i want 3 in each row..

Answer (score 1):

I hope I get your questtion. I think you are asking for a linebreak after every third loop of the foreach.

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
<?php $i=0;?>
<?php foreach ($payment_methods as $payment_method):?>
    <?php if($i++ % 3 == 0){echo "<br>";} /* replace br with tr tags if you want*/ ?>
    <?php if ($payment_method['code'] == $code || !$code): ?>
        <?php $code = $payment_method['code']; ?>
        <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>" id="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>"/>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <label for="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>"><?php echo $payment_method['title']; ?></label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($payment_methods); $i++) {
  // line break after 3 records
  if($i != 0 && $i % 3 == 0)
    echo '<br />';

  if ($payment_methods[$i]['code'] == $code || !$code) {
    $code = $payment_methods[$i]['code'];
    echo '<input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="', $payment_methods[$i]['code'], '" id="', $payment_methods[$i]['code'], '" />';
  }
    echo '<label for="', $payment_methods[$i]['code'], '">', $payment_methods[$i]['title'], '</label>';
}
```